# python subprocess deleting and renaming files

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to delete a file, then rename a file to the deleted file in python.

```
import sys
import subprocess
fileInput = sys.argv[1]
|
|
#code to create fileInput.tmp
|
|
ret=subprocess.Popen("rm "+fileInput,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print ret
ret1=subprocess.Popen("mv "+ fileInput+".tmp "+fileInput,shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
print ret1
```

Whats happening is sometimes (not always) both fileInput and fileInput.tmp are being deleted in `"ret="` step and `"ret1="` step doesn't execute.

Can someone suggest why is it happeing.  This code is run on MacOSx

Comment: Is there a *very good* reason you are using `rm`+`mv` rather than Python functions to do that? It's a very bad idea, and guess what will happen if someone passes `*` as the argument.

Comment: @MichałGórny Thats true.. What should be python equivalent

Comment: Also, is there any reason you need to delete the file instead of simply overwriting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, not answering the question directly but providing a better alternative.

Using `subprocess` here is a *very bad* idea. It is very easy here to end up doing horrible things; you'll at least need to escape the arguments passed to shell.

Instead, use what Python gives you:

```
os.rename(fileInput + '.tmp', fileInput)
```

This is the atomic move/rename operation. And you don't have to `rm` file before replacing it. Moreover, you usually don't do that because between the `rm` and `mv` calls there will be no file with that name. If you just use `mv`, the replacement will be atomic and some file will always be there.

That's all the *short* story, I think.

---

As a side note, `os.rename()` doesn't work across filesystems. So while using it for renaming a file is ok (the source and destination are in the same directory), if you're moving files across different directories you'd rather use:

```
import shutil

shutil.move(src, dst)
```

Comment: Thanks Michal.. Is os.rename platform independent too?

Comment: Yes, it is. It's probably just a wrapper to libc's `rename()` function which is in the standard since the beginning.

Comment: I think they sort them lexically.

Comment: I think they sort them by awesomeness ;)

Answer (score 2):

The first subprocess is not completing, do this:

```
p = subprocess.Popen("...")
p.communicate() # waits until the subprocess completes
```